# How can you add lines to a plot in a previous window?

Tags: r, plot

In MATLAB I can produce a bunch of plots, all in separate Windows, and give each plot a handle which I reference if I want to add extra info to a plot already made.

How do I achieve this in R?

For example, I plot a line in one window. I then plot a line in another window. Now I want to go back to the first window and plot another line.

Now I could organize my code to plot everything I need in one plot, once I have everything needed for the plot, but this is inconvenient in some cases.

I have read the documentation for `?dev` and `?split.screen` but I don't think this is relevant since I am looking for multiple Windows for a given device.

Comment: Just save the plots to a variable like `p <- plot(x,y)` and later add to it like this `p <- p;lines(x2,y2)` or in ggplot by `p<-p+geom_line(data,aes(x,y))` or in plotly with `%>%` etc.

Comment: @Masoud what exactly is the point of `p <- plot(x, y)`

Comment: @rawr You store the plot in a variable, plot it. Later you decide to add something to that plot. You add it to that variable. I am not sure if I got your question correctly. Probably I am giving you a silly answer.

Comment: `plot` has no return value so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @rawr Yeah of course. `p <- recordplot()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dev.set()`

```
graphics.off()
windows() #1st plot
plot(rnorm(20))

windows() #2nd plot
plot(rnorm(20), pch = 19)

dev.set(which = dev.prev()) #make previous plot active
#windows 
#      2 
abline(h = 0) #Draw a line in previous windows
```

Comment: Great! thanks. I see that the key is to call windows(). This opens a window outside of Rstudio. I am guessing the same kind of thing can not be achieved within Rstudio because the plotting tab is considered the same device and is constantly overwritten Is that correct? Just curious.

Comment: @andy, I'm pretty sure you could achieve it with other graphic devices like `png` or `pdf` too. Also try by replacing `windows()` with `dev.new()`